# xmgrace: finding the sum of residuals

Tags: xmgrace

I am using xmgrace's curve fitting option (DATA-->TRANSFORMATION-->REGRESSION), and I want to find the sum of all residuals^2. xmgrace has an option giving me all the residuals, and I already took the square of this, but I want to find the sum of the squares. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Identify the set where `rediduals^2` is kept. Let's say it is `s4`.
- Go to tab <kbd>Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Commands</kbd>. A small window will pop up.
- Assuming you want to sum the `y` of `residual^2` set, type in `s5 point 0,sum(s4.y)`. Press enter. This will add all the `y` values in set `s4` and place it in `y` of `s5`.
- If no error pops up, type in `updateall`. This will update the new set `s5`.
- The sum of `residual^2` will be in `s5(y)`.